# Filter nested v-for list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

```
<div>
    <q-card              
        v-for="box in boxes"
        :key="box.id">
        <q-item>
            <q-item-section>
                <span> {{ box.name }} </span>
            </q-item-section>
        </q-item>

        <q-list>
            <q-item
                v-for="tool in box.tools"
                :key="tool.id"
                clickable
                <q-item-section>
                    <span> {{ tool.name }} </span>
                </q-item-section>            
            </q-item>
        </q-list>
    </q-card>
</div>
```

Form input filter value

```
inputFilterValue = "box A"
```

Filter boxes

Edited with return.

```
computed: {
    boxes(){
      return boxes.filter(box => {
            return box.name.toLowerCase().match(inputFilterValue.toLowerCase())
        });
    }
}
```

This works

How to filter too **nested v-for box-tools list**?

EDITED:

CODEPEN: https://codepen.io/ijose/pen/NWyoRMX

Comment: As per your code `inputFilterValue` containing a `box` name. How you will differentiate that `inputFilterValue` containing box name or tool name or both ? Or do we have separate filters for both `box` and `tool` ? Or in single filter input you want to search for both `box` as well as `tool` name ?

Comment: The goal is to filter both lists of data by the same input string. But the main problem to solve is to be able to filter the nested list. Even with separate filters, how can I filter box.tools?

Comment: I added an answer with working demo, Hope that will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) along with [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method. `some()` method checks if any of the elements in an array pass the function.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    value: null,
    boxes: [],
    dataObj: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Box A',
      tools: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Tool A'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Tool D2'
      }]
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Box B',
      tools: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Tool B'
      }]
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Box C',
      tools: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Tool C'
      }]
    }]
  },
  mounted() {
    this.boxes = structuredClone(this.dataObj);
  },
  methods: {
    inputFilterValue(filterField) {
      if (filterField === 'box') {
        this.boxes = this.dataObj.filter(box => box.name.toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase()))
      } else {
        const filteredToolsArr = this.dataObj.map(box => {
          const filteredTool = box.tools.filter((
            { name }) => name.toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase()));
            return { ...box, tools: filteredTool }
        })
        this.boxes = filteredToolsArr.filter(obj => obj.tools.length);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Filter : <input type="text" v-model="value" @keyup="inputFilterValue('tool')"/>
  <ul v-for="box in boxes" :key="box.id">
    <li>{{ box.name }}</li>
    <ul v-for="tool in box.tools" :key="tool.id">
      <li>{{ tool.name }}</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @ Rohìt Jíndal. I found an unexpected limitation: if in box A there is a second object in addition to Tool A, for example id:2, name: 'Tool D2', and if you filter by Tool A, it will return Tool A and Tool D2 instead of just Tool A. That is, retuen all the tools children of box A

Comment: I've added a example with codepen  to my question, to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve.  In the codepen example, the objective is to filter by Tool A1 and, as a result, only Box A and Tool A1 items are displayed. Example is now just filter boxes.

Comment: @josei After spending a long 2 hours on this, I came up with the solution with two seperate filters logic. one is for `box` and one is for `tool`. I updated the code snippet. Please have a look. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Comment: Thanks Rohìt Jíndal for your help and time spent building this solution. It works very well and will be very useful for other developers.

Answer (score 1):

In the filter callback of `boxes` add a condition if the tool name matches the `inputFilterValue`

```js
computed: {
    boxes(){
        return boxes.filter(box => {
          return box.name.toLowerCase().match(inputFilterValue.toLowerCase()) ||
            box.tools.filter(tool=>tool.name.toLowerCase().match(inputFilterValue.toLowerCase())
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @Boussadjra Brahim thanks. I tried to apply your suggestion in my specific case but it doesn't filter the nested list.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim You forget to add `return` before your `boxes.filter` statement.

Comment: @josei could you provide an example of your data?